# Manually changing nodes in a TensorFlow network

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, neural-network

I have a standard fully connected feedforward network with ReLU activations, which looks like

```
x -> h1 -> h2 -> h3 -> out
```

and I've trained it to learn a simple function (sum the inputs and take `sin`). As an experiment, I want to inject different functions of `x` in the network. So, for example, if `h2` has size `[None, 20]` then I want to set `h2[:,0] = x[:,0]**2` - I want the first node in layer `h2` to be the function that takes the first coordinate of the original input and squares it.

The function `scatter_nd_update` doesn't work because the thing I'm trying to assign to an entry of `h2` is a `Variable`, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't make sense to assign to `h2` anyway. What else can I do?

Comment: There is no problem using `scatter_nd_update` on variables. Are you sure the `indices` and `updates` arguments are correct?

Comment: @SaulloCastro Sorry, I worded it wrong - ``updates`` is a variable, and that gave me an error.